# PLSQL Variables

Tags: sql, variables, subquery, plsqldeveloper, declare

I'm new to programming and I was wonder how I would declare a variable I can use through out my code.

What I want to achieve is :

```
Myvariable = (select Column from table1 where column =1234 group by column);
select column from table2 where column in (myvariable);
select column from table3 where column in (myvariable);
```

and etc

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The tags `sql-server` and `plsql` do not mix.  Are you using Microsoft SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: In sql you can declare variable by `DECLARE @variableName DATATYPE`. And value from select query is assigned  to the variable by `SELECT @variableName = column FROM table WHERE column=1234`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using PL/SQL Developer to access an Oracle database you can create a Test window (File - New - Test Window) with code similar to the following:

```
DECLARE
  myVariable  TABLE1.COLUMN%TYPE := 1234;
BEGIN
  FOR aRow2 IN (SELECT COLUMN
                  FROM TABLE2
                  WHERE COLUMN = myVariable)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE('Do something with ''aRow2''');
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;

  FOR aRow3 IN (SELECT COLUMN
                  FROM TABLE3
                  WHERE COLUMN = myVariable)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE('Do something with ''aRow3''');
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

You'll need to edit the above to do whatever you want with the rows from TABLE2 and TABLE3.

Best of luck.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, I will take a look into this. also does this only work for test window? or can this work for SQL window as well.

Comment: To run this from an SQL window you'd need to highlight all the text from `DECLARE` through `END;` using your mouse, then click the Execute button (or press the F8 key), so it's easier to run it from a Test window where all you have to do is click Execute (or press the F8 key).

Answer (score 0):

this is not really a variable... you can write the sql like this

```
select column 
from table2 
where column in (select Column from table1 where column =1234 group by column);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I wanted to create a tool where I would only have to change that one number once, instead of going through all my code to change where all that number exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary TEMPORARY TABLE bound to the current session:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp
{ 
    column INTEGER 
}
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS  -- Specify PRESERVE ROWS if you want to keep them through commits
NOT LOGGED 
ON ROLLBACK DELETE ROWS  -- Remove this line if you want to keep rows when  you rollback a transaction
```

You load the table:

```
insert into temp1 (select Column from table1 where column =1234 group by column)
```

Then you can use the data using generic code:

```
select column from table2 where column in (select column from temp1);
select column from table3 where column in (select column from temp1);
```